# Cadastro de jogo com postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Olá, eu estou tentando fazer um cadastro de um jogo mas quando tento mandar pelo postman ele não funciona e diz que tudo está nulo

Codigo

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CriarJogo([FromBody] Jogos jogo)
    {
        _contexto.Add(jogo);
        await _contexto.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

postman

```
   {
    "Jogo":{
"JogoNome": "Forza Horizon",
"JogoDescricao": "Jogo de corrida realista.",
 "DataLancamento": "23/10/2012"
           }
   }
```

Model

```
     [Key] 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int JogoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    public string JogoNome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string JogoDescricao { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime DataLancamento { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está chamando a requisição da forma errada, o correto seria assim:

```js
   {
       "JogoNome": "Forza Horizon",
       "JogoDescricao": "Jogo de corrida realista.",
       "DataLancamento": "23/10/2012"
   }
```

Comment: Os valores continuam nulos

Comment: consegue complementar a resposta com a requisição que está realizando no postman? Você pode estar esquecendo de algum detalhe

Comment: eu acabei de refazer meu controller e funcionou

Comment: não sei exatamente qual era o problema, só funcionou

Comment: @LeonardoRocha legal Leonardo, se a minha resposta te ajudou, por favor marque-a como a correta pra que a pergunta seja finalizada.